render CSS on server side (Nextjs)
i have project writed on nextjs + tailwindcss.
my main goal is to convert styles into row styles to get already formated html css content from server side so that will increase website speed performance.
now i have css file which is imported in layout.tsx
but as i see from inspect nextjs is sending request to that css and than renders styles on client side.
Result from inspect -> networks -> docs is this:
my goal is to get already styled response from server like this
i tried many ways like styled components, or css moduls but nothing works so please help me.
i need something that will help me to render css on server side and than send already styled html response instead of only html response without styles.
tnx

CSS renders in the browser when it is received, not sure what you expect "server side rendering" to do.

as you know nextjs has ssr server side rendering so it renders html on server side and send me as response on client side. than nextjs sends response to get styles from client side but instead of this i want from ssr receive already styled html response to make website faster

Some pages display styles in the debug tool because of embedded <style> tags or inline styles in the HTML file. But they are rendered in the browser.

That's HTML, not CSS, it's completely different. Even if the information being sent included "rendered CSS" (whatever you think that is) it will still be required to be read and rendered by the browser. I'm not sure what speed improvement you think that will accomplish.

yes you are partially correct it always render on client side but Styles can be included directly in the HTML document either through 
But I'm not sure it's worth inlining the styles into the HTML. Because http requests are so concurrent these days, one extra request isn't going to be a big overhead. Embedding it in the HTML is able to reduce only one round-trip time, but it makes the browser cache completely invalid for the styles. If two pages contain the same styles, the embedded styles need to be returned separately, whereas the cached style sheet file can be reused directly without sending any requests.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
